# In which py.test callout can I find both 'item' and 'report' data?

Tags: python, pytest

pytest_runtest_makereport() gets two arguments, item and call.  From item, I can find the funcarg I created for this test, and from call, I can find the exception info (if any):

```
def pytest_runtest_makereport (item, call):
    my_funcarg = item.funcargs['name']
    my_funcarg.excinfo = call.excinfo
```

Unfortunately, excinfo is populated for both failures and for skips.  To distinguish, I need to look at the report argument to pytest_report_teststatus():

```
def pytest_report_teststatus (report):
    if report.when == 'call':
        if report.failed:
            failed = True
        elif report.skipped:
            skipped = True
        else:
            passed = True
```

That's great info, but I can't correlate it to the funcarg I created for the test.  I have looked at the report argument (a TestReport report), and I can't find any way to get back to the item passed to pytest_runtest_makereport(), or the funcarg I created.

Where can I get access to both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a little undocumented somewhat unofficial method with which hook implementations can interact with other hook implementations, for example to post-process their result.  In your concrete case you might do something like:

```
@pytest.mark.tryfirst
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call, __multicall__):
    rep = __multicall__.execute()
    # your code follows and you can use rep.passed etc.
    return rep
```

Notes:

- a hook call will usually call multiple hook implementations
- the "tryfirst" marker instructs the hook call to have your implementation be invoked early
- the **multicall** parameter represents the ongoing hook call and can
  be used to call the remaining hook implementations and then
  use their result for further processing
- you need to return "rep" here because you shadow the "real" creation

The **multicall** API is very seldomly really and i suspect there could be solutions for your use case that don't require it.

HTH, Holger

Comment: I finally got a chance to try this, and it works as advertised.  Thanks!

Comment: Very useful for testing with selenium! I can now make pytest take a screenshot using selenium on test failure.

Comment: @viperfx I was just about to say exactly the same thing.

Comment: @pytest.mark.tryfirst
`def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call, __multicall__):
    rep = __multicall__.execute()
    # your code follows and you can use rep.passed etc.
    return rep` this doesn't get called when running with xdist plugin any suggestion please

Answer (score 4):

While hpk42's answer works, `__multicall__` is being depreciated.

This achieves the same result though:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()
    setattr(item, "rep_" + rep.when, rep)
    return rep
```

Comment: This does not work as written: `SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator`

I don't get an error if the `return` statement is removed, though I'm not sure it works as intended.

Comment: As you used yield assignment, I want to know who will call `send()` to `pytest_runtest_makereport`?