# Customizing pytest junitxml failure reports

Tags: python, logging, pytest

I am trying to introspect test failures and include additional data into the junit xml test report. Specifically, this is a suite of functional tests on an external product, and I want to include the product's logs into the failure reports.

Using the method found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754970/in-which-py-test-callout-can-i-find-both-item-and-report-data), I was able to print the logs to stdout before executing the multicall which eventually show in jenkin's fail report. But I'm sure there's a better way to achieve this.

I tried to use the pytest_runtest_logreport hook to append the logs into the 'sections' attribute, which already contains the 'captured stdout' and 'captured stderr' streams. But the newly added sections do not make it to the xml file. I tried the above technique directly into the pytest_runtest_makereport hook as well, with similar results.

The release notes for pytest 2.7 states that using multicall support is being dropped for 2.8 and that @pytest.mark.hookwrapper is the new way to do it, however I can't seem to make that work at all - the "yield" returns None instead of a CallOutcome object (tried it in the makereport hook). And even if it returned something, I'm not sure I could add stuff to it that would show up in the xml report.

Is there any functionality I'm missing that will let me do this in a flexible way? (by flexible I mean: not being bound to stdout or logging calls like the capture-logs plugin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: Since I needed access to the test item's funcargs (and test result) for my reporting, I was able to move the logic to the `pytest_runtest_makereport(item, __multicall__)` hook. The trick is to execute the multicall, which returns the report object:

```
@pytest.mark.tryfirst
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call, __multicall__):
    report = __multicall__.execute()
    # then I was able to manipulate report and get the same results as below
```

---

Bruno's answer gave me the motivation I needed to analyze this feature more thoroughly :)

So here's how it works:

```
def pytest_runtest_logreport(report):
    if report.failed:
        report.longrepr.sections.append(("Header", "Message", "-"))
        report.sections.append(("Captured stdout", "This is added to stdout"))
        report.sections.append(("Captured stderr", "This is added to stderr"))
        report.sections.append(("Custom Section", "This can only be seen in the console - the xml won't have it."))
```

The `longrepr` attribute is only available in case of failures. It takes a 3-tuple, the last value being a character used to decorate the decorate/surround the header. It will appear in the "failure" section of the report:

```
----------------------------------- Header ------------------------------------
Message
```

Custom sections will create additional result sections to be printed out to the ***console***. But they won't make it to junitxml:

```
------------------------------- Custom Section --------------------------------
This can only be seen in the console - the xml won't have it.
```

The junitxml report only has 2 sections: out and err. To add custom text to it, you must create sections called "Captured std" and only those will make it to the xml file. Any other name will result in a custom section that will only be seen in the console.

Here's the resulting junitxml using the code above, with some reformatting for the sake of this post:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<testsuite errors="0" failures="1" name="pytest" skips="0" tests="1" time="0.646">
  <testcase classname="test_reporting" name="test_fail" time="0.000999927520752">
    <failure message="test failure">
      @ut def test_fail(): > assert 0, "It failed"
      E AssertionError: It failed 
      E assert 0 test_reporting.py:346: AssertionError
      ----------------------------------- Header ------------------------------------
      Message
    </failure> 
    <system-out>This is added to stdout</system-out> 
    <system-err>This is added to stderr</system-err> 
  </testcase>
</testsuite>
```

Comment: This solution now produces a deprecation warning for `__multicall__` argument. I wonder if there is a way to avoid it nicely. The only thing I managed to do is to call the pytest original implementation of this hook with `from _pytest.runner import pytest_runtest_makereport as _pytest_runtest_makereport` to get the report

Comment: Yes, you can avoid `__multicall__` deprecation warning by yielding for output report. Inside `pytest_runtest_logreport()` try: 
`outcome = yield`
and then
`report = outcome.get_result()`
`

Answer (score 4):

To add information to a test report (XML, console or otherwise) please take a look at [reporting hooks](http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html?highlight=hooks#reporting-hooks), more specifically at [pytest_runtest_logreport](http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html?highlight=hooks#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_runtest_logreport).

Comment: I didn't mean to make this question junit-specific. What I really need is a way to inject arbitrary data into pytest's failure reports from code. The logging approach works (it's what I'm using) but prevents me from using the '-s' switch (using it will make pytest not capture stdout, and thus logging to console won't make it to junit reports at all).

Comment: Tnx ;) but this hook is already mentioned in my original post... I guess i was using it wrong?

Comment: Sorry about that. Can you post an example and what you were expecting? That hook should be enough.

Comment: I finally got some time to analyze it and posted my findings.

Comment: these links are all broken now.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call)` with `@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)` allows access to the report before it is used to create the xml e.g.

```py
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    result = yield                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    if result.get_result().failed:
        report.longrepr.addsection("Header","message")
```

with pytest-3.9.3

Though [the documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html?highlight=trylast#hookwrapper-executing-around-other-hooks) for hookwrapper does advise caution

> If the result of the underlying hook is a mutable object, they may modify that result but it’s probably better to avoid it.