# Pytest: Less output at the end?

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-django

I execute pytest via PyCharm.

The bottom of the output looks like this:

```
=================================== FAILURES ===================================
__________________ test_get_landing_page_breadcrumb_for_foos ___________________

    @pytest.mark.django_db
    def test_get_landing_page_breadcrumb_for_foos():
        location = Location.objects.create(canonical_name='test-location', name='Test Location', search_volume=1000)
        term = Term.objects.create(canonical_name='test-term', name='Test Term', search_volume=1500)
>       assert 0, get_landing_page_breadcrumb_for_foos(location.canonical_name,
                                             term.canonical_name, PortalFactory.build())
E       AssertionError: [{'@context': 'http://schema.org', '@type': 'BreadcrumbList', 'itemListElement': [{'@type': 'ListItem', 'item': 'https.../test-location/', 'name': 'test-location', 'position': 2}, {'@type': 'ListItem', 'name': 'test-term', 'position': 3}]}]
E       assert 0

test_search_pages.py:12: AssertionError
---------------------------- Captured stdout setup -----------------------------
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: admin_ordering, company_search, compressor, corsheaders, debug_toolbar, django_countries, django_extensions, ...
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, cms, contenttypes, ....
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
Cache table 'file_resubmit_cache' already exists.
---------------------------- Captured stderr setup -----------------------------
Using existing test database for alias 'default' ('test_foofirm')...
=========================== short test summary info ============================
FAILED test_search_pages.py::test_get_landing_page_breadcrumb_for_foos - Asse...
============================== 1 failed in 4.42s ===============================

Process finished with exit code 1


Assertion failed

Assertion failed
```

I would like to reduce the output at the end, since I use "scroll to end" to see the important lines.

I would like the end of the output to look like this:

```
=================================== FAILURES ===================================
__________________ test_get_landing_page_breadcrumb_for_foos ___________________

    @pytest.mark.django_db
    def test_get_landing_page_breadcrumb_for_foos():
        location = Location.objects.create(canonical_name='test-location', name='Test Location', search_volume=1000)
        term = Term.objects.create(canonical_name='test-term', name='Test Term', search_volume=1500)
>       assert 0, get_landing_page_breadcrumb_for_foos(location.canonical_name,
                                             term.canonical_name, PortalFactory.build())
E       AssertionError: [{'@context': 'http://schema.org', '@type': 'BreadcrumbList', 'itemListElement': [{'@type': 'ListItem', 'item': 'https.../test-location/', 'name': 'test-location', 'position': 2}, {'@type': 'ListItem', 'name': 'test-term', 'position': 3}]}]
E       assert 0

test_search_pages.py:12: AssertionError
```

Sometimes the "Captured stdout" is important. But I don't it to be at the bottom. Is there a way to move the "Captured stdout" above "FAILURES"?

```
---------------------------- Captured stdout setup -----------------------------
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: admin_ordering, company_search, compressor, corsheaders, debug_toolbar, django_countries, django_extensions, ...
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, cms, contenttypes, ....
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
Cache table 'file_resubmit_cache' already exists.
---------------------------- Captured stderr setup -----------------------------
Using existing test database for alias 'default' ('test_foofirm')...
=========================== short test summary info ============================
FAILED test_search_pages.py::test_get_landing_page_breadcrumb_for_foos - Asse...
============================== 1 failed in 4.42s ===============================

Process finished with exit code 1


Assertion failed

Assertion failed
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to know more about the [verbose command](https://docs.pytest.org/en/reorganize-docs/new-docs/user/commandlineuseful.html#v-verbose) in Pytest

If you want your output to be less verbose, try `pytest -q` or `pytest --quiet`

Comment: Sorry, I thought about this again. I would like to see "Captured stdout", but above "FAILURES".

Comment: Did you try this answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/29804869/15023296 @guettli

Comment: Thank you for this link. Which reporting hook could do the job? https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=reporting#reporting-hooks